# How can I pass an amount with the gas fee and msg.value in solidity unit test

Tags: solidity, remix, testing, unittesting, remix-tests

Id like to test this function of buyTokens but i can't figure out how to pass the amount of tokens as argument

*This is the test contract*
[image: This is the test function with the test i'm having trouble]

*Function to be tested*
[image: This is the function of the original contract]

Comment: For the next time please include the source as text. That way it is easier to test possible fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking again the problem is that you aren't calling the function, it is missing the parenthesis after the curly brackets.

```
broker.buyTokens{gas: 8000000, value: 1}( NUM_TOKENS );
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, but even after that my test doest pass. Here's the code to test [My Github project](https://github.com/ArtBreguez/Solidity-SimpleBroker)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsLUx.png): [image: The test of assert the balance of account fails but the test of the balance of the broker pass]